# Quaternions question .

Tags: quaternions

its given that :

A quaternion is an expression of the form :

q = $a+b$**i**$+c$**j**+$d$**k**

Where $a,b,c,d$ $∈$ ℝ and $i,j,k$ are basic quaternions, satisfying

$i^2$ =$j^2$=$k^2$= $ijk$ = -1

It's weird that $ijk = -1$.  So $(ijk)*(ijk)$ = $(-1)*(-1) = +1$, but also, $(ijk)*(ijk)$ = $i^2*j^2*k^2$ = $(-1)*(-1)*(-1) = -1$.
Is $ijk$ an operation that's not commutative with quaternions and that's why I just contradicted $ijk=-1$?

Comment: Yes, quaternion multiplication is generally [not commutative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628751/does-the-commutative-property-not-apply-when-multiplying-quaternions)

Comment: In general, you get a minus sign every time you swap two different members of $\{i,j,k\}$ in a product.  So $(ijk)(ijk)=i^2(jk)(jk)=-i^2 j^2 k^2 = +1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but also, $(ijk)*(ijk)$ = $i^2*j^2*k^2$ = $(-1)*(-1)*(-1) = -1$

No. This is invalid. Quaternions *do not commute* in general. You can't just gather the $i$'s to the left, the $j$'s in the middle and the $k$'s to the right.

The point of $ijk=-1$ is to say exactly how $i,j$ and $k$ behave with respect to one another when multiplying. For instance, multiplying by $i$ from the left gives
$$
iijk=-i\\
(i^2)jk=-i\\
-jk=-i\\
jk=i
$$
Instead multiplying with $kj$ from the right gives
$$
ijkkj=-kj\\
ij(k^2)j=-kj\\
-ijj=-kj\\
-i(j^2)=-kj\\
i=-kj\\
kj=-i
$$
(Yes, the factor of $-1$ *does* commute with any quaternion).

So $jk=-kj(=i)$. Similarly we get $ij=-ji$ and $ik=-ki$. Correctly keeping track of this as we sort the $i$'s to the left and the $k$'s to the right will ultimately lead us to
$$
(ijk)(ijk)=-i^2j^2k^2
$$
Note that all throughout I'm liberally using the fact that quaternions are *associative*. Which is to say, i can put parentheses wherever I want when doing multiplication. This is valid for the quaternions, but no longer if you take the next step into octonions.